# Is it posible to create a EventReceiver for opening a site?

Tags: development, visual-studio, event-receivers

I want to start an EventReceiver when a site or a list opens.
How can I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: Hi grekko, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. You're post asks a simple question, but really you have a problem. When you ask here it is always best to state the problem you want to overcome, and then how you think you might overcome it. Someone will then be able to guide you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

for event reciver on a list you can do the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713708(v=office.12).aspx

and

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brianwilson/)

hope it helps :)